# How to extract specific text/string from a field in ELK logs?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elk

In my ELK, a single document has multiple fields (k8s.pod,k8s.ns,timestamp,logtag,steream and message). In the message field, I am getting the logs like below

[36m15:25:47.583[0;39m [1;30m[default-Group-3-11][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [35mc.i.e.s.PaymentGatewayService[0;39m [req_id: 8c5f50d19d664a3c5e533a3257817aae] [x-b3-traceid:] - userId : 261xxxxx == PaymentGatewayService::getEncryptedPayment calling sendSms function

I need to extract the specific text "8c5f50d19d664a3c5e533a3257817aae" which is dynamic for each usecase. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

I tried to check with regex combination and it didn't yield the exact result. I am looking to filter the exact dynamic value, so I can create the visualisation in Grafana with all req ids for that particular use case which can help to aggregate/drilldown etc.,